# crontab can not running shell script

Tags: shell, cron

I have a script, when i write it in `/etc/crontab` it works, but it does not work in the following conditions:

```
crontab -l > wakeup
echo "20 15 * * thu root CALLERID=755 LIST=4001 FILE=hello-world /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/asterisk_wakeup_call.sh" >> wakeup
crontab wakeup
rm wakeup
```

**asterisk_wakeup_call.sh**

```
for element in $LIST
    do
    /usr/bin/touch /tmp/$element.call
    /bin/cat >> /tmp/$element.call <<-EOF
    Channel: SIP/${element}
    Application: Playback
    Data:${FILE}
    Callerid: ${CALLERID}
    EOF
    /bin/mv /tmp/$element.call  /var/spool/asterisk/
    /bin/mv /var/spool/asterisk/$element.call /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing
done
```

I should add:

1. The cron daemon is running
2. The files have permission

please help me to find the mistake.

Comment: What if you use `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`?

Comment: It dosen't work:((